# Find angle of triangle within an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

All i know is that the top left angle is 80 degrees.

Comment: Do you know any trigonometry? The law of cosines, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is famous problem. I borrowed a picture. $\angle BDC=30$ degree.[image]